# Initializing PHP Tooling blocked at 12%

Tags: php, eclipse, eclipse-pdt

There is a [bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=337194) in Eclipse PDT while it's starting up.

[image]

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switching workspace (working adresory) or erasing the current one helped me.

Answer (score 2):

I use Eclipse HELIOS and had this problem. In `workspace/.metadata/.plugins/`, deleting the folders whose name begins with `org.eclipse.dltk` and restarting eclipse worked for me. The folders were rebuilt automatically when I re-opened my workspace.  For Eclipse PDT, also delete folders whose name begins with `org.eclipse.pdt`.

Source: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=337194#c5

Comment: Hmm... I just noticed that the question already included the same link to the bug report that I linked to in my answer. But the solution was also on the bug page.

Comment: I didn't find any folders so I deleted the files (org.eclipse.dltk*.jar) and when I started Eclipse (Mars) a bunch of errors showed up. So I closed Eclipse (now properly instead of "end task") undid the delete of Jar files and started up Eclipse again. BOOM, it works now! O.O

Comment: On a new restart the problem returned :( in my case it is stuck at 0%.